# Dimensions in the PAM method

Tags: clustering

I am just starting my adventure with data analysis. And I have a problem with understanding the results obtained in the PAM method. Could someone explain to me in a simple way what are these two dimensions Dim1 and Dim2 obtained in this method?
[image]

Above I present an example visualization of the results of the PAM method in which my data has been divided into 5 clusters. I understand what mediodes are but unfortunately I don't understand what these Dim1 and Dim2 are.

Comment: PAM produces a clustering.  You are showing us a graph. What method did you use to create the graph?

Comment: The graph was prepared in R using the `fviz_cluster` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `fviz_cluster` says:

> Observations are represented by points in the plot, using principal
> components if ncol(data) > 2.

so, presumably, you had more than two dimensions.  In order to make a two dimensional graph, `fviz_cluster` used principal components analysis and used the first two principal components to display your data. Notice that the axes are labeled `Dim1 (62%)` and `Dim2 (7%)`. This means that the first principal component accounts for 62% of the variation in the data and component 2 accounts for an additional 7% of the variation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was actually simple. I was a bit confused with these names Dimm1 and Dimm2.